# Integrating Factor/Initial Value Problem with Trig

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

The problem is as follows:

Solve the initial value problem $$9(\sin(t)\frac{dy}{dt} + \cos(t)y) = (\cos(t))(\sin(t))^3, $$  for $ 0 < t < \pi$ and $y(\pi/2) = 9$.

---

So far I have this by dividing by $9\sin(t)$: 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + cot(t)y = \frac{\cot(t)\sin^2(t)}{9}, $$

Then used the integrating factor of $e^{\cot(t)}$ in order to get:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\cot(t)}y) = e^{\cot(t)} \frac{\cot(t)\sin^2(t)}{9}, $$
I do not know how to proceed from here as the integration itself is complex and my current process does not seem to be right.

Comment: That is a typo; thanks for catching that

Comment: Isn't your integrating factor $\displaystyle e^{\int \cot(t)/9~dt} = \sqrt[9]{\sin t}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you divide through, the coefficient on $y$ is also divided by 9,
and the rhs should have $\cos$ not $\cot$.

Second, the integrating factor is $e^{\int \cot t/9 \; dt}$, which, as Moo says, turns out to be $\sqrt[9]{\sin t}$.  This makes the "hard" integral on the rhs into a fairly easy $u$-sub.

Comment: Thanks for the help; it seems that I made a lot of mathematical mistakes on this one.